# youtube-dl with replay of live events

Tags: youtube-dl

I used `youtube-dl` to get a live event. The result is a file of over 3 GB that plays on VLC and Quicktime in 5 seconds and skims over the several hours of footage.

How can I download a live event onto a proper movie file?

**Update**: This happens differently for some events. The question was after [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwzvNAAqH3g). With [this one](https://youtu.be/e-YyvEXc2bQ), it works just fine (it's the livestream itself that was cut at 1:00:00).